# How to map ntext using NHibernate Mapping-By-Code feature of NHibernate 3.2?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, truncate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code, ntext

I need to map ntext column of a table using the mapping by code feature in NHibernate 3.2, so that it doesn't get truncated to 4000 characters.

What do I neet to change in the following example? "Notes" is the property which has ntext type in sql table:

Property(emp => emp.Notes);

Note: Please don't mix it with fluent NHibernate or hbm file mapping.

Comment: `NTEXT` is obsolete. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx. Use nvarchar instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I solved the problem as following:

> Property(emp => emp.Notes, map => map.Column(col =>
>   col.SqlType("ntext")));

Actually, all what we need to do is: tell the NHibernate mapper the actual type of the column in sql. :)

The solution comes from [here](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/mssql-legacy-data-types-in-nhibernate-mapping-bycode-conformist/) as pointed by [jbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236044/jbl).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this, which should also work for nvarchar(max) columns :

```
Property(emp => emp.Notes, m => m.Type(NHibernateUtil.StringClob));
```

Hope this will help

Comment: It doesn't work since it expects type of "Notes" to be nvarchar(MAX) instead of ntext.

Comment: @Baig ok, thx. I hope this can be of some help http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/mssql-legacy-data-types-in-nhibernate-mapping-bycode-conformist/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Property(emp => emp.Notes, mapinfo => mapinfo.Lenth(someHighValue));
```

If the length provided is larger than what can fit in a varchar, NHibernate will switch to a different character type.

Comment: It will switch to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.